# I tried to update wordpress version through filezilla (FTP)

Tags: php, wordpress

From my local computer I replaced
wp_admin
Wp_content
wp_include plus many more files except .htaccess, wp_confi.php

But i got below error, can anyone help me with this, please!! I have no cpanel as i am using ultimate wordpress hosting of godaddy.

Warning: require_once(**DIR**/admin.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/94/7890694/html/plus/wp-admin/index.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/admin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/94/7890694/html/plus/wp-admin/index.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

1. Download your wp-content folder and your wp-config.php file.
2. Download a copy of your sites database from a tool like phpmyadmin.
3. Upload a fresh copy of wordpress (do not run the installer)
4. Replace the wp-content folder with your own.
5. Replace the wp-config.php with your own.

Log into the site admin, you may see a message that says its updating the database, this is normal. This should resolve your issue.